# How to preserve kendo Ui Grid filters on next time page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to store(preserve) kendo UI grid filters for next time page load,

For ex:
On 1st time page load i have filter with value x and then i move to other page and again come back to grid page then by default my page load with value x filter which i had last applied.

Can kendo grid provide that type of functionality? if not then can any one give me idea or hint that how to achieve this.

Comment: You can store your filter value to the `TempData` and use it when you need to apply filter again.

Comment: if you search google for the title of your question, the [second result](http://www.telerik.com/forums/remember-kendo-grid-state-(current-page-current-sort-filter-selected-record-etc)-while-loading-back-grid) (after your own question on stackoverflow here) shows you how to do it

Answer (score 0):

you cant do on page reload as kendo is just a frontend component and is entirely dependent on is javascript file so when you reload the page you lose all the data stored in javascript so you can retain filter on grid reload but if you want to retain after page reload you have to use `session storage` or `html local storage` or `cache memory` or  `TempData variable (if u are using mvc)` just google it to know more about them